# Sublime Text 3 Warning PHP 7.0 or newer is required

Tags: phpmyadmin, php7, sublimetext3, wamp

estaba usando la version **PHP 7.0** desde **SublimeText 3**. Probando un pequeño ejemplo:

```
<?php 


    //VARIABLES

    $uno = 123;

    echo $uno; 

 ?>
```

Al guardarlo (dentro de directorio `/www`) **SublimeText** me lanza una **ventana de error**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando le doy a **Aceptar** me sale la siguiente **ventana de error** :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por otra parte, he **comprobado la version** de mi **PHP** desde la **terminal** con el siguiente comando :

`php -v`

obteniendo lo siguiente :

```
PHP 7.2.4 (cli) (built: Mar 28 2018 04:27:01) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

Por tanto se supone que la version que me pedia esta **arrancando** entonces no entiendo porque sigue saliendo el error.

Finalmente me gustaria puntualizar que cuando le doy al icono de `wamp` en la parte inferior derecha de la pantalla con el **click izquierdo** me sale en el panel un Warning relacionado con el `PATH` dejo una imagen del caso:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero alguien sepa como solucionarlo ya que no me permite **acceder a mis ficheros.php** Gracias y un saludo

Comment: Quizá esto te pueda servir de ayuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52463287/i-am-getting-error-in-wamp-for-php-in-path

Comment: Gracias @JoseManuelMorales ya habia encontrado una solucion, la publico para quien le surja el mismo problema. Un saludo y gracias nuevamente.

Answer (score 1):

Ya encontre la forma de solucionarlo.

Me he tenido que ir a mi **SublimeText**

Abrir `Preferences/Package Settings/phpfmt/Settings- User`

Al fichero que se nos abra lo editaremos de la siguiente manera :

```
  {
    "psr2": true,
    "version": 1,
    "php_bin" "php_bin":"C:\\wamp64\\bin\\php\\php7.2.4\\php.exe",
}
```

Donde `php_bin` debe ser la ruta de tu **php.exe** de la **version** de **PHP** que te interese